# Boost Asio and Web Sockets?

Tags: boost-asio, websocket

Does anyone know of any attempt to implement the [Web Sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) API using Boost asio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu) implemented WebSockets on top of boost::asio.

Answer (score 17):

I realize this is an old thread, but wanted to update to help those looking for an answer: [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp) fits the bill perfectly. Wt is an entire framework and may be more than many people want.

Answer (score 5):

[Beast](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast) is another project, demonstrated at [CppCon 2016](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinniefalco/Beast/master/doc/images/CppCon2016.pdf) and used in [rippled](https://github.com/ripple/rippled), an open source server application that implements a decentralized cryptocurrency system.

Also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561179/does-boostasio-support-websockets).

Answer (score 1):

The closest example I know of anyone doing anything remotely like what you're asking is the [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) project.  There is an increasing amount of discussion on the Mongoose mailing list about persistent connections for HTTP - but that's obviously not exactly Web Sockets.  I would hope that someone would be able to add Web Sockets to it, too, eventually.

Comment: Use comments, not answers, to, well, *comment*.

Comment: @gf, okay, turned it into an attempt at an answer.