# How can I use use C++ to send data through a websocket?

Tags: javascript, c++, http, websocket

I want to be able to send data over a websocket in my C++ code? Is there some library or standard way that this is done? Thanks for the help, I appreciate it, and please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: What is your OS and compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147715/i-am-looking-for-a-simple-socket-interface-for-c-using-ms-visual-c-express/4147766

Comment: @anand: I don't think websockets are quite the same as sockets.

Comment: It is however a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please have a look at https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp,
which is based on Boost ASIO.

You can find a comparison of websocket implementations at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library.

Comment: Does Boost::Asio support Websockets as of now? The last time I checked they did not. Note, that Websockets are not identical to normal sockets.

Answer (score 1):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) is probably going to be a little bit more highlevel and easier to use than boost, esp if this is HTTP you are looking at.

Comment: are you sure will it work for websocket ? Note http and websocket are related but different technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link to libwebsocket [in the answer of warmcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library/4809124#4809124) to [my question (Standalone C++ websocket server library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library) which was posted earlier.

Note that libwebsocket can be used for client and server side websockets.

Answer (score 1):

[Beast](https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast) is a C++ library using Boost Asio, demonstrated at [CppCon 2016](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinniefalco/Beast/master/doc/images/CppCon2016.pdf) and used in [rippled](https://github.com/ripple/rippled), an open source server application that implements a decentralized cryptocurrency system.

Also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561179/does-boostasio-support-websockets) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894469/boost-asio-and-web-sockets).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different ones, but you'd probably find the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure C++ approach to WebSockets using Boost.Asio check out: https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-WebSocket-Server